# Adding the file sizes of Get-ChildItem listing

Tags: powershell, filesize, get-childitem

My goal is to figure out how much space all images on my network drives are taking up.

So my command to retrieve a list of all images is this:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -include *jpg,*bmp,*png \\server01\folder
```

Then I would like to just retrieve the file size (`Length`).

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -include *jpg,*bmp,*png \\server01\folder | Select-Object -property Length
```

Now this outputs:

```
                                         Length
                                         ------
                                         85554
                                         54841
                                         87129
                                        843314
```

I don't know why it is aligned to the right, but I want to grab each length and add them all together. I am lost and have tried every thing I know (which isn't much since I am new to PS), tried searching Google but couldn't find any relevant results.

Any help or alternative methods are appreciated!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use the `Measure-Object` cmdlet:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *jpg,*bmp,*png \\server01\folder
$totalSize = ($files | Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum
```

To get the size in GB divide the value by `1GB`:

```
$totalSize = ($files | Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum / 1GB
```

Comment: For any who'd like a one-liner version: `(Get-ChildItem -Path \\server01\folder -Recurse -Include *jpg,*bmp,*png | Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum`

Answer (score 13):

You could do this as a one liner with something like this.

```
Get-Childitem -path  "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer" | Select-Object 
Name, @{Name="KBytes";Expression={ "{0:N0}" -f ($_.Length / 1KB) }}

Name          KBytes
----          ------
en-US         0
images        0
SIGNUP        0
ExtExport.exe 52
hmmapi.dll    53
iediagcmd.exe 500
ieinstal.exe  490
ielowutil.exe 219
IEShims.dll   398
iexplore.exe  805
sqmapi.dll    49
```